# How to fix method cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program to do a binary search.

The method should be repeated a different number of times and and i want to print out the time it took to repeat the method.

They way the code is now i get an error while compiling method binary search cannot be compiled to  given types and i  dont know how to fix it.

```
public class Bin_search  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double k = (int)(Math.random()*1000001);
        int n = 1000000;
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int t= 0; t<z; t++) {
        binarySearch();
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("It took " + elapsedTime + " ms to repeat the algorithm.");
        }
        int binarySearch(int n, double k, int arr[]) {
            int li = 0;
            int re = n+1;
            int m;
            while (li <  re-1) {
                m = (li + re) / 2;
                if (k <=arr[m]){
                    re = m;
                }
                else{
                    li = m;
                }
            }
            return re;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please, post your stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the binarySearch method is made by three arguments, and you are not providing them, secondly you should make your binarySearch method static, otherwise it cannot be called from the main method without creating an instance first.

It should be like this, i think

```
public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        args = new String[3];
        args[0] = "100";
        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double k = (int)(Math.random() * 1000001);
        int n = 1000000;
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int t= 0; t<z; t++) {
        binarySearch(n, k, arr);
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("It took " + elapsedTime + " ms to repeat the algorithm.");
        }

    static int binarySearch(int n, double k, int arr[]) {
            int li = 0;
            int re = n+1;
            int m;
            while (li <  re-1) {
                m = (li + re) / 2;
                if (k <=arr[m]){
                    re = m;
                }
                else{
                    li = m;
                }
            }
            return re;
        }
}
```

**EDIT**: Now it works, but please check if your application logic to be sure it's doing what you are expecting to do

Comment: I can compile it now, but when i want to try the code i get the error Could not find or load main class.

Comment: I also tried it with your code and get the same eror.

Comment: This happen because i have renamed your class from Bin_search to Main, just change it again, it will work

Comment: No, this had nothing to do with it i just couldnt run java "programs" from 1 sec to another anymore. I would say the error referenced the system-variables you have to set when you install JDK. Although they were set right.

Comment: A day later i randomly started working again. Now i  need to run a java "program" in the compiler with java classname.java. It isnt as it should be but i am happy it at least works again.